# Asynchronous fetching with Core Data on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm a little unsure as to how to fetch data from disk to a managed object context asynchronously.

I was reading up the docs and learned that with a parent-child relationship, I could have the parent context running on a private queue and the child context on the main thread. Executing a fetch request on the child context would then propagate to the parent, which does the fetch from disk asynchronously. However, how would the child context know when the fetch is complete? (so that the data could be retrieved by the view controller and use it to update the UI)

Is there a notification the child context receives?  (According to the docs, the NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification is not triggered during a fetch request)

And if not, can someone suggest the best way for me to fetch data asynchronously from disk?

P.S: I have ONE solution for this so far, described below. 
Have 2 contexts (no parent-child relationship), one on the main queue and one on a private queue. The context on the private queue does a fetch. Once this fetch is complete on the background thread, the object IDs of fetched objects are stored and existingObjectWithID:error:(NSError **)error is called for each objectID that's fetched on the main thread for the main context. The fetch re-occurs on the main thread this time, however, since core-data caches fetched objects, the fetch on the main thread is then a lot faster as it reads from the cache and not the disk.

However, this seems to depend on the cache and if I'm loading a lot of data, it will not be as efficient if the cache is too small.

Comment: So you're saying that even if a fetch 10 million objects, it's not going to be freeze the UI? The worry for me isn't the memory, but it's the time it takes to fetch a large amount of objects.

Comment: I see your problem now. I was thinking about memory consumption, not time execution :( The solution you propose sounds good. Also, see the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that child contexts automatically push the **changes** that happen on their context (inserts, updates or deletes change the dataset, **but reads/fetchs don't!**) to their parent. So, when fetching data you are not changing the context, thus no notification is sent. However, you can send your own notifications using `NSNotificationCenter` or a custom `delegate` callback when you have finished fetching data.

If you are inserting a great amount of data, you can move that work off the main thread/context to a background thread/context, setting the main context as the parent of the newly-created, background child context. So when inserts have finished on the background context, changes are automatically pushed to the parent, main thread/context.

You should also take a look at Florian Kluger's post[1] about performance differences between 3 common Core Data stacks.

[1] http://floriankugler.com/2013/04/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout/

**EDIT:** I fully understand your problem now. Fetching a large amount of data on the main thread context will freeze your UI. You have to use an `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest` on the main thread context, providing a completion block. See this example: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-core-data-and-asynchronous-fetching--cms-22241

Comment: So, you suggest a custom notification/delegate method call once the fetching on the background thread is complete?

Comment: If i was using a child-parent relationship, then calling the fetch method on the child, propagates it to the parent, and I'll be able to access it from the thread of the child anyway, even though the parent is executing the fetch on a background thread. But if fetches are not time expensive, like you say, then it shouldn't be a problem at all. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I read about that but I need to support iOS 7 and that works on iOS 8 only.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is the `NSManagedObjectContext` that caches the objects, and not the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, fetching a large amount of objects and then running `existingObjectWithID:error:(NSError **)error` will cause the `NSManagedObjectContext` to perform one I/O operations per uncached object. If you can, I'd recommend to set up an `NSFetchedResultsController` and allow it to do fetching in batches.

If you do the fetch on the background context first, and pass the `NSManagedObjectID`-array to the main thread, this predicate `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self IN %@", objectIDs];` will ensure you only fetch the objects you found on your background thread.

Comment: What about the other suggestion of using the parent-child context architecture? I would place the parent on a private queue, child on the main thread. When I call fetch on the child context, it is passed up to the parent context that does the fetching on a separate thread. I could then call a delegate method to inform an object on the main thread that the fetching is complete, and then the NSManagedObjects could be accessed from the child context. 

What do you suggest about this?

Comment: Fetching on a main thread context will block the main thread. If you are not doing a complex query or you don't need all the objects at once, I'd recommend a NSFetchedresultsController doing batched fetching for you

Comment: I need all objects at once, unfortunately.

Comment: I agree with Audun, you should do batched fetching of, say, 50 items per batch. That would do the job to display all the items on screen in a TableView. But, I guess you need all objects at once to perform some calculations on the whole data? If so, check the use of NSExpressions: http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/